# mySql stored proc not returning data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am accustom to working in MS SQL and am floundering to get this mySql stored proc working!

I know there is data to be pulled but nothing returns.

```
DELIMITER //
/*  Author: Jessie Brown     
    Date:   8/17/13 
    Notes:  Template Creation

    Comments: Comments created in the header area will NOT be stored in the database write
              Comments created AFTer the begin statement will be retained within the database write
*/

-- checks to see if stored procedure exists
-- if exists the procedure is dropped and recreated

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `reportLogExceptions`//

-- Creates new procedure

CREATE PROCEDURE reportLogExceptions (IN logId varchar(50),
    IN groupId varchar(50),
    IN fromDate varchar (50),
    IN toDate varchar(50))

  BEGIN
      /*
        report name: Log Exceptions
        Test Query: CALL reportLogExceptions('1','1','1378385650','1378472050')
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Declare variables*/

      DECLARE logInS varchar(50);
      DECLARE groupIdS varchar (50);

    /*
      Sets the variables to use for the SELECT query
    */
      CASE
        WHEN logInS = '-1' THEN
        SET logInS = ''%'';
         ELSE SET logInS = logInS;
      END CASE;

      CASE
        WHEN groupIdS = '-1' THEN
        SET groupIdS = ''%'';
          Else SET groupIdS = groupIdS;   END Case;

  SELECT g.groupId,g.name AS groupName,l.logId,l.name AS logName, i.itemID,
      i.name AS itemName, le.userName,completed, i.optimalMin,i.optimalMax ,value
  FROM groups g
      JOIN LOGS l ON g.groupID = l.groupId
      JOIN logExceptions le ON l.logID = le.logID
      JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId
  WHERE  l.logID LIKE logInS
      AND g.groupID LIKE groupIdS 
      AND le.completed
        BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate / 1000)
        AND FROM_UNIXTIME (toDate / 1000);
  END//

DELIMITER ;
```

To call the stored procedure I am using

```
CALL reportLogExceptions('-1','-1','    1359676800','1362095999')
```

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error? I don't think MySQL uses `''%''` syntax. I think it should be `SET groupIdS = '%';`.

Comment: What data type is `le.completed` of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing logic in your `CASE` statements is invalid.

Instead of referring to input parameters `logId` and `groupId` you compare `logInS` and `groupIdS` to themselves respectively. Thus you always get `NULL`s as values in these variables.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf1cf/2)** demo that shows that

You most likely meant to have this

```sql
SET logInS   = CASE logId   WHEN '-1' THEN '%' ELSE logId END;
SET groupIdS = CASE groupId WHEN '-1' THEN '%' ELSE groupId END;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42163/2)** demo.

Also your choice of using `VARCHAR` for all parameters seems to be strange. Use appropriate data types (e.g. `INT` for `logId` and `groupId` and `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` or `INT` for `fromDate` and `toDate` depending on what data type is used for `logExceptions.completed` column).

Comment: PROGRESS! I did have to remove the fromDate and toDate until I figure out how they are passed so I am working on just the case piece of the code now!  I used the code above to replace my case statements. The issue I run into now is when logId or groupId = anything other than -1 I get no data return. for instance if I use CALL reportLogExceptions('1','3') I get no data returned. The reason I have everything as a varChar is I was told by the client that all variables are passed as a string, which is why I was trying to convert fromDate and toDate within in the query.

Comment: I found the issue for the case statements. I needed to adjust the order in which they variables were sent (groupId,logId) as opposed to the other way around. Now I just need to tackle the toDate and fromDate - any suggestions? Also WOW on the sqlFiddle tool - do you have any tutorials on how to use this tool! Thank you again for all you help!

Comment: @Portlight You're quite welcome :) To help you with dates you have to answer my question what data type is `completed` column in `logExceptions` table is of.

Comment: the datatype is a timestamp - the code that i using [AND le.completed
      BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate / 1000)
      AND FROM_UNIXTIME (toDate / 1000)] is from the original report - when speaking to the stakeholder he said that the 'toDate' was passed as a string but somehow that is just not making sense. I changed the declared IN type and now I get a error when executing - '1 Incorrect datetime value: '1359676800' for column 'fromDate' at row 1 SQL.sql 1 1 '  suggestions?

Comment: @Portlight If it is `timestamp` datatype (and not `int` representing Unix epoch time) then you don't need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()`. Just pass and use datetime literals as is and your condition should look just `BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate`.

Comment: I am a bit confused - Yes the completed column is a timestamp BUT the value being passed is supposedly a string! how would I parse it if they are sending a string over

Comment: You don't need to parse it. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d41a/1) example for you. That being said I highly recommend to change data types of parameters to be as follows `IN logId INT, IN groupId INT, IN fromDate TIMESTAMP, IN toDate TIMESTAMP`. You gain nothing having data type being `VARCHAR`.

Comment: OK but what i am saying is that the dates ARE NOT sent to the query as '2013-09-02 00:00:00' they are sent as unix time - that I can not change.

Comment: @Portlight Sorry, didn't pay attention. Well your procedure parameters then should all be of type `INT`. And a `WHERE` condition should be `... BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate)`. Here is updated [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32dbab/1). Take a look at `sp_dates1()`. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I opened another question related to this in hopes of getting help and to prevent what is turning into discussion  question name:  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687820/passing-milliseconds-into-stored-procedure-mysql[/link]