# Passing milliseconds into stored procedure mySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a strange something going on with my stored proc. I am passing an int into the stored proc - when i pass as the value as a epoch time the stored procedure works
passing that same value as the int in milliseconds it DOES not work

passing 1360292312 (int) into FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate)  works (give the correct translation)

passing 1360292312000 (int) into FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000) does not work (not giving me what i expect)

why is that - do i need to change the type to bigINT?

Comment: That ought to work, and works correctly in my testing. Are you certain that `fromDate` contains the value `1360292312000` as expected?

Comment: Post the stored procedure definition. It may well be that you need a larger INT type for the parameter.

Comment: absolutely -i could load my proc but not sure how on this site  here is the code    BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate / 1000)
      AND FROM_UNIXTIME (toDate / 1000)  here is what i am passing CALL reportLogExceptions('3','-1',1365250024000,1369827488000)  now i know those dates are in the database because i used them to get the range for ints - this in making me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with `signed int` max value. You must divide the number by  1000 before sending it to `FROM_UNIXTIME()`. More importantly, it should be less than or equal to the max value of signed int.

`signed int` can only go up to 2147483647 and from what I see `FROM_UNIXTIME` works or any value up to that. If you pass 2147483647+1 it returns null.

Query and the results -

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1360292312), #February, 08 2013 02:58:32+0000
        FROM_UNIXTIME(1360292312000),  #(null)
        FROM_UNIXTIME(1360292312000/1000), #February, 08 2013 02:58:32+0000
        FROM_UNIXTIME(2147483647), #January, 19 2038 03:14:07+0000
        FROM_UNIXTIME(2147483648), #(null)
        FROM_UNIXTIME(4294967295) #(null)
```

see fiddle [examples](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96658/5)

Integer type [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

FROM_UNIXTIME [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)